# Delete unused sockets geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I have a `Group Output` node that I accidently added extra input sockets to.
[image]

Even when I delete the node and add a new `Group output` node, the extra inputs are there.  Is there a way I can delete them, and not just hide them?

Comment: Press 'N' to open the side panel and then click the Group tab. Those outputs should be listed in the Outputs list and you should be able to select each spurious one in turn and click the '-' icon to delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As John commented, press "N", then click "Group" tab.

Then select the outputs you want to delete and click the "-".

[image]